# Foreign key constraint issue with uniqueness validation test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

Running Rails 4.2.8

I've added a new model with a foreign_key of `user_id`. While functionally everything seems to work fine, when I run a test confirming the uniqueness validation of `user_id` I am getting a `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey` error. Details below.

migration

```
create_table :standard_accounts do |t|
  t.timestamps null: false
  t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

model

```
class StandardAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id  
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

structure.sql (we're using strucuture.sql rather than schema for annoying reasons)

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.standard_accounts
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_6bc98ede2c FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.users(id);
```

test

```
RSpec.describe StripeStandardAccount, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:user_id) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id) }
  ...
```

test failure

```
1) StandardAccount should validate that :user_id is case-sensitively unique
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id) }

 ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
   PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "standard_accounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_6bc98ede2c"
   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(0) is not present in table "users".
   : UPDATE "standard_accounts" SET "user_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "standard_accounts"."id" = $3
 # ./spec/models/standard_account_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::ForeignKeyViolation:
 #   ERROR:  insert or update on table "standard_accounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_6bc98ede2c"
 #   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(0) is not present in table "users".
```

I suppose I could edit the migration and remove the `foreign_key: true` bit (which is what is presumably creating the foreign key constraint in structure.sql), but that was added by Rails default generator, and while I'm not exactly sure what its purpose is, it seems like there's something else wrong here, cause this should be working as is.

Comment: It sounds like it might be complaining because there isn't a user with that ID in the `users` table, so the reference is invalid? What if you create a user in your test— do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error.

Comment: Can you share the code doing so?

Comment: @JakeShorty I just added `setup { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` to the beginning of the test to test your suggestion.

Comment: Is it still trying to use a `user_id` of `0` after that?

Comment: Yep, still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way around this problem is to create an instance of your `StripeStandardAccount` object *before* you run your shoulda test. For example:

```rb
  # Step 1
  # If you are using FactoryBot (note: you need to use "!" with your "let")
  let!(:stripe_standard_account) { create(:stripe_standard_account) }

  # If you're not using FactoryBot
  StripeStandardAccount.create(your-required-params-go-here)

  # Step 2
  # Then run your shoulda_matcher test
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id) }
```

This is because your test case needs an existing instance to compare to the instance it is creating. You can't ask a single instance of an object if it is unique. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/682#issuecomment-78124438

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is actually due to a bug in the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) library. I was able to solve it using [this approach](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/682#issuecomment-187767983).